# Helmholtz equation in a circle with nonhomogeneous boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, fourier-transform

I'm looking to solve the Helmholtz equation $$\Delta u + k^2u = 0$$ Or in polar form $$u_{rr} + \frac{u_r}{r} + \frac{u_{\theta\theta}}{r^2}+k^2u=0$$ In the circle of radius $a$, with boundary conditions $$u(a,\theta)=f(\theta)$$ Where of course $f$ is a periodic function with $f(\theta+2\pi)=f(\theta)$ for all $\theta$.

I could easily find several sites where a solution was given for $f=0$ by using separation of variables, but is there any way of solving this for any function $f$? Is it still possible to use separation of variables with non-zero boundaries? If not, I would like to find a numerical solution to $u(r,\theta)$ by using finite differences in the polar grid and the DFT (Discrete Fourier Transform).

Thank you very much.

Comment: For reference, Mathworld has a page on the separation of variables of the Helmholtz equation in polar coordinates: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HelmholtzDifferentialEquationPolarCoordinates.html. Moreover, that $f\neq 0$ on the boundary really isn't a barrier to use of separation of variables; the general solution they give, for instance, won't vanish at $r=0$ and will have nontrivial $\theta$-dependence. (Typo alert: Should be $Y_m(kr)$ in their last equation.)

Comment: @Semiclassical And how could I find the values of the constants $A_m, B_m, C_m, D_m$ that they use? I would like to plot the solution to this problem and I don't know how to find them for a given function $f$ in the boundary, but I can't solve that system for that many variables. How many terms of that series should I consider if I have $N$ points or, reversely, how many points should I consider in the grid to know exactly $M$ terms or the series? I don't know how to handle those expressions.

Comment: Basically, evaluate the general solution at various limits e.g. $r=0,r=a$. You also need to know a bit about how the Bessel functions behave at small arguments. You'll also need to know the Fourier series of $f(\theta)$. But this is all fairly standard separation of variables material; I'd suggest you read up on that first in a book on applied math methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The separation of variables leads to an infinity of solutions which sum express the general solution. The periodic solutions are selected and the respective coefficients are computed in order to agree with the boundary condition (expressed on the form of a Fourier series) :

[image]